# Lower estimate for $\int_0^T f(x) \sin f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry

Let $T>0$ and $f:[0, T]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $|f^{\prime}(x)|<1$ for all $x$ and $f(0)=f(T)$, $f^{\prime}(0) = f^{\prime}(T)$.

I need a lower bound for the integral
$$\int_0^T f(x) \sin f(x) dx. $$

I tried integrating by parts but I am not sure about my computations. I have:
$$\int_0^T f(x) \sin f(x) dx=[-f(x)\cos f(x)]_0^T +\int_0^T (f^{\prime}(x))^2\cos f(x) dx = \int_0^T (f^{\prime}(x))^2\cos f(x) dx.$$
${\bf Edit}$: computation edited availing of @JackT's comment.

How to gain a lower estimate for this integral?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\frac d {dx }\cos f(x) = - (\sin f(x)) f’(x)$ not $-\sin f(x)$ so you have applied integration by parts incorrectly

Comment: A very clumsy lower bound  obtained from bounding the integrand from below by a constant is $-T\text{sgn} \{f(0)-T\}(f(0)-T)$ but I guess you are looking for something sharper?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio no, it is fine also to have a constant as lower bound.

Comment: This problem is equivalently $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $|f'(x)| < T$, $f(0) = f(1)$, $f'(0) = f'(1)$, and find a lower bound for $T\int_0^1 f(x)\sin f(x)dx$. This form may be easier to work with.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio That simplifies to $-T|f(0) - T|$.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio could you give more details? Or also eyeballfrog. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks. not sure why I didn't simplify that as such lol

Comment: @User1010 I initially deleted my answer with the details, but I will undelete it for you to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very clumsy lower bound. By the mean value theorem, for $x\in (0,T)$ we have for some $c\in (0,x)$

$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(c)x>f(0)-T,$$

the inequality from the fact $|f'(c)|<1.$

Since $\sin f(x)\in [-1,1]$,  the integrand is at least $$-|f(0)-T|$$ imputing a lower bound for the integral of

$$-T|f(0)-T|.$$

Comment: Golden_Ratio, do you mean $\int_0^T f(x) \sin f(x) dx>-T|f(0)-T|$ without using first the integration by parts I started with?

Comment: @User1010 Yea i didn't use parts. I just bounded the integrand by a constant, and then integrated the constant

Comment: @User1010 On a separate note, I don't really agree with your application of parts due to JackT's critique, i.e. $\sin f(x)dx\neq d\cos f(x)$

Comment: Golden_Ratio, thank you!

Comment: @User1010 No prob. My answer doesn't really use all the facts you are given though, but it is a bound to start with ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Golden_Ratio, either way it is the best place to start! :)